Open cv.VideoCapture(index) - ffmpeg list camera names - How to match?
    def fetch_camera_input_settings(self):
        try:
            self.database_functions = database_functions

            self.camera_input_device_name = database_functions.read_setting("camera_input_device_name")["value"]
            self.camera_input_device_number = int(self.database_functions.read_setting("camera_input_device_number")["value"])

            self.camera_input_devices = [[0,-1,"Καμία συσκευή κάμερας"]]
            self.available_cameras = [{"device_index":-1,"device_name":"Καμία συσκευή κάμερας"}]

            # FFmpeg command to list video capture devices on Windows
            cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true", "-f", "dshow", "-i", "dummy"]
            result = subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
            output = result.stderr  # FFmpeg sends device listing to stderr

            # Updated regular expression to capture both video and audio devices
            device_pattern = re.compile(r'\[dshow @ .+?\] "(.*?)" \(video\)')
            cameras = device_pattern.findall(output)
            counter = 0
            for camera in cameras:
                counter += 1
                self.camera_input_devices.append([counter,counter-1,camera])
                self.available_cameras.append({"device_index": counter-1, "device_name": camera})

            self.to_emitter.send({"type":"available_devices","devices":self.camera_input_devices,"device_index":self.camera_input_device_number})
        except:
            error_message = traceback.format_exc()
            self.to_emitter.send({"type":"error","error_message":error_message})


How to match ffmpeg camera device names output with cv2.VideoCapture which wants camera index as input?
